# Flow direction from point layer displayed wrong

Tags: qgis, vector, flow-direction

I have a point shapefile layer containing surface flow velocity information: x and y, magnitude and direction in degree angle. I have used graduated symbology with a colour filled arrow symbol to display these over a basemap and flood depth layers. The flow direction angle is displayed wrong however and I cannot figure out why. The available angle range is 0 to 360 so adding or removing a fixed amount to try and correct for a false starting angle does not work properly. Could someone help please?

The image with the black arrows is the correct one and the one with the red graduated ones is from QGIS. Do not mind the differences in water depth display.

[image: The flow arrows in QGIS showing up at odd angles to flow direction]

[image: Black flow arrows are the correct ones from the hydraulic model]